# Is it possible to install Xcode 4.3 and Xcode 4.5 side-by-side on Mac OS X 10.7.4?

Tags: xcode

Is it possible to install Xcode 4.3 and Xcode 4.5 side-by-side on Mac OS X 10.7.4?

I'd like to install the preview but would rather have some confirmation before going ahead.

The [Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_4.5_developer_preview/xcode_45dp_rn.pdf) make no mention of Xcode 4.3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, if you download your Xcode versions from the [developer site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/), you can just put them in two different folders. They can even be installed in the same folder if you give the .app bundles two different names.

You can also keep both icons in the Dock.

Comment: Just to add that you can only have one set of command line tools installed since they both go to the same location.

Comment: The information is very helpful. Thanks.
Just asking: if I open an old project with xCode 4.5, would that update its structure and make the project unable to be opened with xCode 4.3?

Comment: I haven't had much experience with 4.5 but so far no problems, and with 4.4 it worked really well.

Comment: take care: any update of Xcode 4.5 will (e.g. 4.5.1) might update or remove other Xcode instances, even on other partitions than the start partition.

Comment: @brainray Are you sure that does not depend on how you install it? My answer presumes you install from a disk image (when I wrote it, that was the only way). Will edit the answer to include this.

Comment: @Monolo: I had 2 versions of Xcode in my Applications folder, first 4.4.1, then I added the GM, when it was available. As soon as Xcode was released to the public, the 4.4.1 version was updated and the GM was removed. Also libraries of an older Xcode version on another partition have been changed. There are ways to keep both versions - I just wanted to point out, that it might be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally for command line tools use command xcode-select to switch current xcode.