# build/compile app for iOS 4.2 through iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Support both armv6 and iOS 6 in an App Store app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12574851/support-both-armv6-and-ios-6-in-an-app-store-app)

Up to now, I've been building my app using "armv6 armv7" and iOS 4.2+.

With Xcode 4.5x and iOS 6, it seems I can't do this anymore.
I've tried adding "armv6" to the existing "armv7" and "armv7s"
and I've tried removing "armv7s"
but I still get warnings when I Analyze:

"warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/MyApp/main.m' of type sourcecode.c.objc for architecture armv6"

Plus iOS 4.2 no longer shows for "Depolyment Target"

Is there a way to build my app for iOS 4.2 - 6 ?

Comment: There are many questions about this on StackOverflow (similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12574851/558933).  You need to install a previous version of Xcode . See the following question about multiple XCodes (there are others) http://stackoverflow.com/q/11001069/558933.

Comment: Yes, there are similar questions but a lot are confusing. I resolved this by downloading XCode 4.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can do 4.3 - 6, or 4.2 and 6 in a separate app. There is no way of supporting 4.3 - 6 in one app.

Comment: That stinks because I can't even support my own iPod any more?

Comment: You must have a second or first generation then. The second one is now  4 years old, the first one 5. Maybe you should consider upgrading...?